# AspectJ to not advise calls from the target object

Tags: aspectj

The following aspect `around` is executed for all fields in classes that inherit from `PersistedEntity` (except those provided by `Object`).

```java
aspect MyAspect {
    pointcut entityCall(PersistedEntity persistedEntity):
        get(* *) &&
        target(persistedEntity);

    Object around(PersistedEntity persistedEntity): entityCall(persistedEntity) 
    {
         if( ...some conditions... )
             return proceed(persistedEntity);
         throw some exception...;
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to *not* execute the aspect `around` if the call is *coming from* the object itself. Is that possible? Could you point me in the right direction? Your help much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you are applying a few false assumptions about how AspectJ works and what the pointcut types mean. So I have a few questions in order to understand what you actually want to do: (1) What do you mean by "getters"? Execution of methods like `getName()` or `getId()` or read access to member variables like `this.name` and `this.id`? (2) Whatever you answer in (1), why would you exclude access from `Object`? Firstly `Object` does not have any members or getters, secondly JDK classes are not intercepted by AspectJ anyway. So it doubly does not make sense. I have more questions later.

Comment: (1) Yes, you're right, it's not just about getters, but about field access, I'll update the question. (2) Excluding `Object` is a remnant of where I started working off of, It can go. Thanks for improving my aspects with me :)

Comment: So if it is about field access and you want to exclude internal access, I conclude that you have a situation in which external classes directly access members, i.e. they are not encapsulated in a Java Bean way. This does not sound like particularly good application design, BTW. My goal in asking this is mainly to understand it, though. Is this really what you are doing? Some sample application code illustrating what you are trying to explain in prose would be helpful.

Comment: No, most of the time these fields are accessed through their respective getters, in which case the aspect is fired, to my satisfaction. Example: `Object1.method()` calls `SomePersistedEntity.getName()`, which accesses `SomePersistedEntity.name` field, aspect is executed. `Object1.method()` calls `SomePersistedEntity.isValid()`, which accesses `SomePersistedEntity.name` field, which should not execute the aspect. I kept writing this to completion, but now realize that there is no way I can express this in an aspect, except by moving from fields to methods (getters) in my aspect definition :)

Comment: I did not say you cannot do it, I just have a hard time understanding what you actually want, thus the question about sample code. Do you mean that you want to exclude class-internal field access from methods with names other than `get*()`?